# Invalid form with FileField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have an `UpdateView` with an object which has a `FileField`. If the model has a file uploaded, I show the link to the file, and also a file input in case the user wants to update it.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% if object.file %}<a href="{{ object.file.url}}">Download</a>{% endif %}
    <input type="file" name="{{ form.file.name }}">
    <input type="text" name="{{ form.other_field.name }}">
</form>
```

which works fine if the object is new and does not have a file, in which case the Download link does not show or if it has a file, in which case the Download link shows up.

But, if I select a file to upload, and the form is invalid, the `object.file` field exists, and it points to a non-existent file.

Is there a way to tell in an invalid form if the file is real?

Comment: Check this [example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **enctype**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I did use it, just forgot to add it in the example.